# Actor Critic based on keras where state is image

Tags: tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, tensor

I have a basic implementation of actor-critic based on keras. It works for standards open ai gym.

```
    def __init__(self, alpha, beta, gamma=0.99, n_actions=4,
                 layer1_size=1024, layer2_size=512, input_dims=8):
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta
        self.input_dims = input_dims
        self.fc1_dims = layer1_size
        self.fc2_dims = layer2_size
        self.n_actions = n_actions

        self.actor, self.critic, self.policy = self.build_actor_critic_network()
        self.action_space = [i for i in range(n_actions)]

    def build_actor_critic_network(self):
        input = Input(shape=(self.input_dims,))
        delta = Input(shape=[1])
        dense1 = Dense(self.fc1_dims, activation='relu')(input)
        dense2 = Dense(self.fc2_dims, activation='relu')(dense1)
        probs = Dense(self.n_actions, activation='softmax')(dense2)
        values = Dense(1, activation='linear')(dense2)

        def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
            out = K.clip(y_pred, 1e-8, 1-1e-8)
            log_lik = y_true*K.log(out)

            return K.sum(-log_lik*delta)

        actor = Model(inputs=[input, delta], outputs=[probs])

        actor.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=self.alpha), loss=custom_loss)

        critic = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[values])

        critic.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=self.beta), loss='mean_squared_error')

        policy = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[probs])

        return actor, critic, policy

    def choose_action(self, observation):
        state = observation[np.newaxis, :]
        probabilities = self.policy.predict(state)[0]
        print('make probabilities')
        action = np.random.choice(self.action_space, p=probabilities)
        return action

    def learn(self, state, action, reward, state_, done):
        state = state[np.newaxis,:]
        state_ = state_[np.newaxis,:]
        critic_value_ = self.critic.predict(state_)
        critic_value = self.critic.predict(state)

        target = reward + self.gamma*critic_value_*(1-int(done))
        delta = target - critic_value

        actions = np.zeros([1, self.n_actions])
        actions[np.arange(1), action] = 1

        self.actor.fit([state, delta], actions, verbose=0)

        self.critic.fit(state, target, verbose=0)
```

I want to change the `observation` in the `choose_action` method  to an image, the image is a screenshot, grey scale, size=256*256. The `self.predict.policy()` method take as input a numpy array, tensor or `tf.data` dataset. When I convert the image to the tensor, I get an error: "ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 4 but received input with shape [None, 445]"